# how to deal with single quotation marks in postgresql functions

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a pg function which need to be deal with single quotation marks.

```
create or replace function deal_null_value(in user_id numeric) returns integer as
$body$
    declare
        part_num integer;
        sql_str character varying;
    begin
        sql_str := '
        select b.num from (
            select regexp_split_to_table(together,E',\\s*') as together,
            count(id) as num
            from inc_info t
            where
            t.registime>=to_timestamp('2011-10-01 00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mi:ss')
            and t.registime<=to_timestamp('2011-10-31 23:59:59','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mi:ss')
            group by together_person
        ) as b 
        where cast(b.together as integer) = ' || user_id;

    EXECUTE sql_str into part_num;
    return part_num;
    end;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

you see I have some single quotation marks.

```
regexp_split_to_table(together,E',\\s*')
to_timestamp('2011-10-01 00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mi:ss')
```

I want to use $$ to instead of ' and I want to use quote_literal function, how can I use it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Mu already answered the question about quoting and @araqnid cleared up casting issues. There is a number of issues left that warrant another answer. Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION deal_null_value(IN user_id numeric, OUT part_num integer)
  AS
$body$
DECLARE
    sql_str  text;
BEGIN
sql_str := $x$
    SELECT b.num FROM (
        SELECT regexp_split_to_table(together, ',') AS together_person
              ,count(*)::integer as num
        FROM   inc_info t
        WHERE  registime >= '2011-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp
        AND    registime  < '2011-11-01 00:00:00'::timestamp
        GROUP  BY together_person
    ) b 
    WHERE  b.together::numeric = $1
    $x$;

EXECUTE sql_str
INTO    part_num
USING   user_id;

END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

#### Major points:

- This is **illegal** and will provoke an error:

  ```
  to_timestamp('2011-10-01 00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mi:ss')
  ```

  It would have to be:

  ```
  to_timestamp('2011-10-01 00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss')
  ```

  But better simplify to:

  ```
  '2011-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp
  ```

  **ISO 8601** timestamp format is **valid with *any* locale**. No need to spell out the format, this is the standard.
- Replace

  ```
  registime  <= '2011-10-31 23:59:59'::timestamp
  ```

  with

  ```
  registime  < '2011-11-01 00:00:00'::timestamp
  ```

  Timestamps can have fractional seconds. You would miss something like

  ```
  '2011-10-31 23:59:59.034'::timestamp
  ```

  ... and have a very hard time to find out why.

- Simplify

  ```
  regexp_split_to_table(together,E',\\s*') as together
  ```

  to

  ```
  regexp_split_to_table(together, ',') AS together
  ```

  Also, I suspect, you want to call it

  ```
  regexp_split_to_table(together, ',') AS together_person
  ```

  as you group by it further down. You cast to numeric (or integer) later. **Leading / trailing white space is trimmed automatically** in both of those casts. So, no need for an escape sequence or a more complicated regular expression. Faster, cleaner.
- `count(*)` instead of `count(id)`, **if** id is NOT NULL (as I assume). `count(*)` is faster.
- Aggregate function `count()` returns `bigint`. Cast it to `integer` as you return integer. No problem here, as it is cast automatically, but may become a problem in other situations.
- Use an [OUT parameter](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) for `part_num` to simplify the code. Then, after assigning to `part_num`, you don't need an explicit `RETURN` statement.
- Why would you cast `b.together` to `integer`? You compare it to a `numeric` `user_id`? Either make `user_id` `integer`, too, or cast to `numeric`!

#### Concerning performance of `count(*)` vs. `count(col)`

1) Think about it: `count(*)` only checks for the existence of rows, while `count(col)` must also check whether `col` is `NULL`. ([NULL values don't count!](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html))
2) Try for yourself with any big table:

```
`EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(*) from tbl`
```

versus

```
`EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(col) from tbl`.
```

If a the column `col` is defined `NOT NULL` or you *know*, there cannot be NULL values, then `count(*)` yields the same result as `count(col)`. Use `count(*)` in such a case, it is a bit faster.

Comment: +1 for thoroughness and a better way to avoid quoting madness.

Comment: count(*) instead of count(id), if id is NOT NULL (as I assume). count(*) is faste. I am not sure it's right, but everyone told me that coutn(id) is faster.

Comment: @diligent: Well, "everyone" should get their facts straight. :) I amended my answer with more info on that. BTW, it is `count(*)`, not `count()`. The markdown format swallows the `*` if you don't escape it.

Answer (score 2):

[Dollar quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) is pretty straight forward: just pick a token (optional), put it between dollar signs (`$token$`), and use that like a quote:

```
    sql_str := $sql$
    select b.num from (
        select regexp_split_to_table(together,E',\\s*') as together,
        count(id) as num
        from inc_info t
        where
        t.registime>=to_timestamp('2011-10-01 00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mi:ss')
        and t.registime<=to_timestamp('2011-10-31 23:59:59','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mi:ss')
        group by together_person
    ) as b 
    where cast(b.together as integer) = $sql$ || user_id;
```

You can use [`quote_literal`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) like any other string function:

```
    where cast(b.together as integer) = cast($sql$ || quote_literal(user_id) || $sql$ as integer)$sql$;
```

Your `user_id` is numeric though so you probably don't need it; OTOH, I don't think it can hurt.

Comment: Using quote_literal on a numeric value will put it into the SQL statement as a text value, so it might need casting again. That is, `cast(b.together as integer) = cast($sql$ || quote_literal(user_id) || $sql$ as integer)`

Comment: @araqnid Better yet, apply the [USING clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) to hand in values without casting to and from text representation. Thereby eliminating possible SQLi, simplifying the code and speeding up execution. A win-win-win situation. :)

Comment: yes, that's even better. I'd forgotten it was possible to do that with an EXECUTE statement.

Comment: @araqnid: Right you are, thanks. I was interpreting my `select quote_literal(11)` checking wrong. Fixed.

Comment: @araqnid: The `USING` for `EXECUTE` statements was only introduced in v8.4. So, my solution will not work with 8.3 or older.